# wix register already DII on Server

Tags: com, wix, installation

there are some COM dll on server f.e. "\server\proj\worker.dll" installed with "setup_server.msi"

On each client a setup "setup_client.msi" should be run, that registers that dlls on the client, but the msi should NOT contain the worker.dll.

something like

```
<Component ...>
  <File ... Source="...\worker.dll">
     <TypeLib ...>
        ...
```

includes the file into MSI. that work's fine for "setup_server.msi", but I don't want include the files in "setup_client.msi".

Of cource, with `<RegistryValue>` it is possible to make all entries manually, but then I have also to include the typelibrary into the client installer. This doesn't help.

So, is there a simple way to say wix "take the existing file \server\proj\worker.dll and simple register it -or at least the typelibrary- on client"?

Comment: Does it work via DCOM? (instantiate object remotely on the server itself): https://ss64.com/vb/createobject.html - [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22251105/129130). I haven't worked on legacy COM  in ages, so check if there are new restrictions and disable anti-virus for testing, etc... I would check with lead developer. [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model).

Comment: thanks, but it does not belong to DCOM.
my problem is, that I don't want that a Client-Setup installs some files. Only the Server-Setup shall install files and the Client-Setup shall only register existing files.

Comment: Why wouldn't worker.dll be registered by the server.msi?

Comment: Having one msi install a file and another msi register it seems like a component rule violation to me.